# Conditional parallelism on LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am writing an application to update the numeric value given user's input value and depending on the user's input value the program checks if it is greater than 10 if it is greater than 10 then the program waits for 1 second and then will have a popup message says "true".

My intention was to call the conditional check, printing true every one second if the user's input value is greater than 10; in other words, the case structure was to be called regardless of the event structure in the same loop infinitely.

But it doesn't seem to work the way I expected. Unless there is user's new input value, getting into the event structure, the program doesn't get to the case structure even though the case structure is in a loop.

Is there any way to call the case structure not dependent to the event structure but I want to use a shift register for the numerical value and also having an event structure and a case structure in parallel.

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You've created an Event Structure that handles the `Value Change` input for your numeric control, so that will do exactly what it says: wait for a Value Change event to happen. When that event is received, the code in its Event Structure frame will execute and then the Event Structure will exit.

It looks as if you've wired a value from the shift register to the `timeout` terminal of the Event Structure, so I assume you must also have created a `Timeout` event case? If so, the event structure should stop waiting after the number of milliseconds wired to the timeout terminal.

The value you check in order to decide whether to show your `true` message is the value that was passed in to the shift register on the previous loop iteration. If the control value changes, that comes from the `NewVal` terminal in the Value Changed event case. But where does it come from in the timeout case? It looks to me as if you haven't wired it in that case, because the terminal coming out of the event structure has a little dot in it instead of being solid orange. That means you will get a **default value** for any case where the terminal wasn't wired. The default value for numerics is zero. So if the event structure times out, the value going in to the shift register is zero, you get zero out of the shift register on the next iteration, zero is not greater than 10, so you don't see the message again.

I don't understand what you're trying to do in the event case where you've wired the `NewVal` terminal to a `Value` property node of the same control. Can you explain what that is supposed to achieve?

Your question reads as if this is a programming exercise where you have to use these specific LabVIEW structures, so rather than suggest better ways of achieving what you say you want this code to do, I'll leave it to you to decide how to change it. In the meantime though I do recommend re-reading the [Event Structure help](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/event_structure/) and the [caveats and recommendations](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvhowto/caveatsrecmndtnsevnts/) it links to.